# eclipse emulator keeps relaunching intead of using the one already lauched

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

it takes forever for my atom processor sony to lauch the emulator after about 20 minutes of loading I get

```
[2012-04-10 13:20:06 - killthemall-training] Failed to install killthemall-training.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-04-10 13:20:06 - killthemall-training] (null)
[2012-04-10 13:20:06 - killthemall-training] Launch canceled!
```

when I hit run again it starts launching a while new emulator and the failed install cycle continues. How do I get it to use the emulator I already finally have launched?

I also read having the adk in the program file folder causes long launch issues because of the space.

Answer (score 0):

i found unchecking "wipe user data" in run configurations kept a new emulator from coming up each time. i had to check this earlier for another issue i was having.